# Como ler um arquivo texto e gerar um dicionário?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Escreva a função `símbolo()` que aceite uma `string` (o nome de um arquivo: **nasdaq.txt**) como entrada.

O arquivo terá nomes de empresa e símbolos de ações. Nesse arquivo, um nome de empresa ocupará uma linha e seu símbolo de ação estará na linha seguinte. Após essa linha estará uma linha com outro nome de empresa e assim por diante. Seu programa lerá o arquivo e armazenará o nome e o símbolo da ação em um dicionário.

arquivo (parte dele):

```
ACTIVISION INC      
ATVI
ADOBE SYS INC
ADBE
ALTERA CORP     
ALTR
AMAZON  
AMZN
AMERICAN POWER CONVER CORP  
APCC
AMGEN   
AMGN
APOLLO GROUP-A  
APOL
```

arquivo completo: https://easyupload.io/x6v37a

O que eu fiz:

```
def simbolo(arquivo):
    empresas = {}
    with open("nasdaq.txt") as f:
     texto = f.read()
     for i in range(len(texto.split("\n")) - 1) :
        empresas.setdefault(texto.split("\n")[i],texto.split("\n")[i+1])
    return empresas


empresas = simbolo("nasdaq.txt")
print(empresas)
```

O problema é que o dicionário está ficando errado com vários "\t":

```
{'ACTIVISION INC  \t': 'ATVI', 'ATVI': 'ADOBE SYS INC', 'ADOBE SYS INC': 'ADBE', 'ADBE': 'ALTERA CORP \t', 'ALTERA CORP \t': 'ALTR', 'ALTR': 'AMAZON \t', 'AMAZON \t': 'AMZN', 'AMZN': 'AMERICAN POWER CONVER CORP \t', 'AMERICAN POWER CONVER CORP \t': 'APCC', 'APCC': 'AMGEN \t', 'AMGEN \t': 'AMGN', 'AMGN': 'APOLLO GROUP-A \t', 'APOLLO GROUP-A \t': 'APOL', 'APOL': 'APPLE}
```

Alguma ideia para resolver? O que estou fazendo errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Além do caractere `\t`, existem espaços vazios em excesso no arquivo de txt. É possível utilizar uma combinação dos métodos de string `strip()` e `replace()`. Antes de mostrar o código, vou apresentar um breve exemplo de como esse código funciona. Suponha que você tenha a seguinte *string*:

```
sentence = 'Todos os animais são iguais, \tmas uns são mais que os outros     '
```

Como lembrado por outro usuário, o computador interpreta `\t`como se você tivesse teclado a tecla `tab` e, assim, considera `\t`como sendo 4 espaços. Para ver isso, basta ver a versão formatada da *string* usando o print:

```
 print(sentence)
```

Output:

```
Todos os animais são iguais,     mas uns são mais que os outros
```

Note que, além do caractere `\t`, existe um excesso de espaços no final da string que foram criados usando a tecla de espaço mesmo. Para eliminar esses espaços criados sem o tab, podemos utilizar o método `strip()`. Veja:

```
sentence = sentence.strip()
print(sentence)
```

Output:

```
Todos os animais são iguais,     mas uns são mais que os outros
```

Para remover o caractere `\t`, podemos utilizar o comando replace:

```
sentence = sentence.replace('\t','')
print(sentence)
```

Output:

```
'Todos os animais são iguais, mas uns são mais que os outros'
```

Naturalmente, como o output do método `strip()` também é uma *string*, podemos aplicar os métodos de forma encadeada:

```
sentence.strip().replace('\t', '')
```

Aplicando esses conceitos à sua função, temos:

```
def simbolo(arquivo):
    empresas = {}
    with open("nasdaq.txt") as f:
     texto = f.read()
     for i in range(len(texto.split("\n")) - 1) :
        empresas.setdefault(texto.split("\n")[i].strip().replace('\t',''),texto.split("\n")[i+1].strip().replace('\t',''))
    return empresas


empresas = simbolo("nasdaq.txt")
print(empresas)
```

Comment: @Lucas: O arquivo texto está em https://easyupload.io/x6v37a

Comment: Ok. Chequei aqui. Era isso mesmo. Vou editar minha resposta para incluir a remoção do '\t'

Comment: @Lucas: poderia, por favor, explicar em mais detalhes?

Answer (score 1):

Em Python a sequencia de escape `\t` significa *TAB*. Para substituir os caracteres *TAB* por espaço use:

```
string.replace("\t", " ")
```

No seu código:

```
def simbolo(arquivo):
    empresas = {}
    with open("nasdaq.txt") as f:
     texto = f.read().replace("\t", " ") # terminada a leitura faz as substituições
     for i in range(len(texto.split("\n")) - 1) :
        empresas.setdefault(texto.split("\n")[i],texto.split("\n")[i+1])
    return empresas


empresas = simbolo("nasdaq.txt")
print(empresas)
```

Veja o código funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/KhakiThistleInfo)

Answer (score 1):

```
def simbolo(arquivo):
    empresas = {}
    with open("nasdaq.txt") as f:
     texto = f.read()
    #print(texto)

    caracteres = ["\t"]
    for i in caracteres:
        texto = texto.replace(i, " ")
    texto = texto.split("\n")
    texto_novo = [i.strip() for i in texto if len(i)>0]
    #print(texto_novo)
    i = 0
    while i < len(texto_novo) -1:
        empresas[texto_novo[i]] = texto_novo[i+1]
        i+=2
    return empresas





empresas = simbolo("nasdaq.txt")
print(empresas)
```